# Get changes in .css that where not made using compass

Tags: sass, diff, compass

Lets Say I have this structure of files

```
/sass/screen.scss
/sass/file1.scss
/css/screen.css
```

And I left it all good, the thing is other developer took over the project and he didn't know I used compass  and he Did many changes directly to the `screen.css`

So I guess you can imagine that I am asking about this because I took over the project again...

Is there a pseudo automatic way of putting all the changes not included in the `.scss` files so I can create another `.scss` with all them and continue using compass just with an `import?`

It's like when you commit, you get the diff; but copying line by line would be too much time consuming.

Comment: Would it be a way to first cut the file `screen.css` and place it somewhere else, then generate the `screen.scss` again so that you have two css files. One with the adjusted screen.css and one with the generated scss(old). When you have two CSS files you can compare the difference with this tool: http://www.alanhart.co.uk/tools/compare-css.php   is that a possibility?

Comment: then if you have the difference you can use this tool to convert it to sass: http://sebastianpontow.de/css2compass/

Comment: @Pierezzz The thing is that with that site,  I get the diffs marked, and I can copy and paste (TOO much time consuming..), what would like idealy to find is a serivices that generates an output for the diffs, so  that can be my `new.scss`

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem and solved it by doing the following:

1. Compile or convert your css file (the wrong one) to a nested version
   (regular multiline css). You can do that using a local editor or
   use [this online tool](http://www.styleneat.com/) and save it to
   another location or as a duplicate
2. compile your (the right one) sass library to screen.css (nested or multiline)
3. Download [UltraCompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/ultracompare_download.html).
   You can download a fully working 30 day trail version. 4 Open both
   files in the editor
4. In the top toolbar press the red = sign (Just Differences). And it
   will show you all the diffs of the files
5. Copy/paste the diffs and run it through a sassify parser [like this
   one](http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/)
6. Save it as your new.scss

Comment: Oh, that's weird! Could you post links to the 2 css files?

Comment: The second one isn't converted right. All the content in the icons are converted to {content: ""}. Tha's why the compare show all of them